# Jquery nested each functions

Tags: jquery

I have cloned some radio buttons, attached to each row in a page.  When I try to loop through them to 'check' the correct radio button on page load, it is only working on the vary last one.

Here is the problem isolated on Codepen:
http://codepen.io/trinzia/pen/dpOoRk

```
var buttonpanel = $("#sectionbuttons");
$('section').each(attachRowButtons);

function attachRowButtons(i, elem) {

  var newpanel = buttonpanel.clone(true, true);
  $(elem).append(newpanel);
  newpanel.removeAttr("id").removeClass('collapse');

  var d = $(elem).data('type');
  if (d) {

    newpanel.find('input[name="myradio"]:radio').each(getType);

    function getType(i, elem) {

      var n = $(this).val().search(d);

      if (n > -1) {
        $(this).prop("checked", "checked"); //correct
      }
    }


  }

}
```

If you look at the codepen, you will see that, even though each row gets a match, only the last radio button set is ever checked.  I need to get the value checked correctly (radio checked=checked), one per each row.

Thanks!

Comment: only one radio can be checked per group (radios with the same "name" attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update the js please  Link : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrWVEr

```
var buttonpanel = $("#sectionbuttons");
  $('section').each( attachRowButtons );

  function attachRowButtons (i, elem) {

    var index=i; //Add this line .......................................
    var newpanel = buttonpanel.clone(true, true);
    $(elem).append( newpanel );
    newpanel.removeAttr( "id" ).removeClass('collapse');

    var d = $(elem).data('type');
    if ( d ) {

      //Checked="checked" on radio buttons at page load
      newpanel.find( 'input[name="myradio"]:radio').each(getType);
      function getType(i,elem) {
        $(this).prop("name", "myradio"+index); //Add this line .......................................
        var n = $(this).val().search(d); 

        if ( n > -1 ) {
          $(this).prop("checked", "checked"); //correct
        }
      }


    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you only ever have 1 radio button checked is because they all share the same name attribute "myradio". You will need to change the names of the cloned inputs before they can be a separate group.

You could do that with something like:

```
var newpanel = buttonpanel.clone(true, true);
newpanel.find('input').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('name', 'anothername');
});
```

And later when you find the input elements within the panels, you should change:

```
newpanel.find('input[name="myradio"]:radio').each(getType);
```

to

```
newpanel.find('input:radio').each(getType);
```

Comment: You can also change the name after you've selected them: `newpanel.find( 'input[name="myradio"]:radio').attr('name', 'myradio'+i).each(getType);`

Comment: Thanks, you are both correct!  (Can only choose one, so took the one with example.)  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Already you have two correct answers. Yes the issue was with the `same named radio buttons`. Since you already figured it out with other answers, I would like to make the code simpler while checking the radio button.

You can make your code this simple inside your `if(d)` block

```
if ( d ) {     
 newpanel.find( 'input[name="myradio"][value="'+ d +'"]')
   .prop("name","random" + i)
   .prop("checked", "checked");
}
```

You can use a `value` selector instead of looping and trying to find the one matching with the value.